# How to Fetch line number in application (client) using sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to fetch few information's from multiple tables using a select statement. All the tables are related to one single part of my Application (client). There are multiple entries in the application. For example let say 180 entries. The line number of these entries are not marked in any table. But while i am fetching the information using select statement i would want to know from which line of the entries in application my result is coming from. 
Is there any ways to achieve this.

I am using Oracle database.

Comment: What do you mean by "There are multiple entries in application"? What are the tables and what do you mean by line number?Show us your query with tables(and relevant joins) and what is the expected output.

Comment: Rows in a table don't have "line numbers". Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO package to do what you want:

- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS003
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dbms_application_info
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_in_dbms_application_info_set_module__what_makes_the_module_name.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can add the pseudo-column `rownum` to your query with something like:

```
select rownum, q.* from (... your query with order by clause...) q;
```